# chrome window.openで複数タブ開くには

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

javascriptです。
window.openで複数のタブを開こうと以下のようなコードを書きました。

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myfunc(){
  window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank")
  window.open("http://www.yahoo.co.jp","_blank")
  window.open("http://www.msdn.com","_blank")
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" name="btn" onclick="myfunc()">ボタン</button>
</body>
</html>
```

IEだと期待通り3つのタブが開くのですがchromeだと一つのタブしか開きません。
chromeで期待通り3つのタブを開くようにするにはどうすればよいでしょうか。
ポップアップの許可なども試してみたのですがだめでした。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: まことに申し訳ないんですが、ポップアップ許可で上手く行きました。許可するサイトにyahoo,google,msdnを追加しただけだったのがまずかったようで
全部許可にしたら期待通り動きました。